# Bootstrap file not linking

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

My bootstrap files are not linking with my HTML file. Hence, they are unable to give the correct output.I have downloaded the bootstrap 4 files in my machine and using it rather than referring to web. I had downloaded it and extracted it .

```
npm install bootstrap@4.0.0 --save
npm install jquery@3.3.1 popper.js@1.12.9 --save
```

I used these to commands to setup bootstrap file in my project directory.

This is the link to my github repo

https://github.com/SMAmmar/bootstrap

Comment: i dont see any linked css file in your html files , you may want to link them first

Comment: please check now ,I accidentally added the link to wrong repository.

Comment: if your node_modules folder and html file are in the same directory , add **./** in the first of address , if in different , use **../** to go to previous folders : 
if same directory :
**<link rel="stylesheet" href="./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">**

Comment: Well they are present in the same directory ,but the snippet you gave is not working

Comment: check with your IDE auto complete , try to writing address from the first and see if IDE suggests you , if not , address is wrong

Comment: sure will do it.